# Firefox don't play html5 videos on youtube

Tags: release-loki, kernel, 64-bit

With kernel vmlinuz-4.4.0-62-generic firefox don't play html5 videos on youtube, boot with 4.4.0-59-generic play ok. help?

Comment: the kernel is irrelevant. your issue is related to firefox only.

Comment: can you elaborate on "don't play videos"? do they not display at all? Are they corrupt? Do you get sound? Is the video intermittent? Do they just not play at full screen?